# How to fix this gnu issue this is my output

Tags: g++

[Running] cd "c:\Users\dead\Documents\vs code\C++" && g++ new -o c:\Users\dead\Documents\vs code\C++\new && "c:\Users\dead\Documents\vs code\C++"c:\Users\dead\Documents\vs code\C++\new
g++: error: code\C++\new: No such file or directory

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.455 seconds

Comment: `g++` expects an input file named `new.cpp` or `new.cxx`, not just `new`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner).

In your output, you are trying to build a file called `new`, this is not acceptable by g++, you should change its name with `.cpp` or `.cxx` end.